# UnicodeDecodeError while opening file named by non-English chars in PyQGIS 3.X

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, unicodedecodeerror

I tried to open files named partially in Chinese via PyQGIS, the error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 73: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().homePath()
source_file = "/buffer_prac/1A27_八德店.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "Response_X", "Response_Y")
uri = "file:/" + root + source_file

A27_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "A27", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(A27_lyr)
```

The file can be opened manually by *Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer*. The file can also be opened properly while changing the file name into English.

I have checked solutions suggesting to change via `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`,
however I later discovered that it is not encouraged to do so and it seems not working in my case either.

How can I open the file without changing filename via PyQGIS?

Comment: which line throws the error? and have you tried looking to see how the GUI code handles file names?

Comment: Hi @lan, I have updated the error message it shows on the console. How can I check the code runs by GUI?

Comment: qgis source is at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src